# Use declared table type variable for inserts postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table from which I select ids:

```
SELECT  Ids
FROM    C 
WHERE  C.Type = 6
```

Then I have a lot of inserts, that use the same ids:

```
    INSERT INTO D (x, y, z)
    SELECT 20 as x, 2.90 as y, z FROM C WHERE Ids in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    INSERT INTO D (x, y, z)
    SELECT 11 as x, 33 as y, z FROM C WHERE Ids in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    INSERT INTO D (x, y, z)
    SELECT 12 as x, 2.11 as y, z FROM C WHERE Ids in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

since these Ids are the same, I want to somehow optimize it/make it more readable so that I wouldn't copy paste all these ids (there are several hundred of them).
For this reason I would like to declare table type variable, insert these ids into that table and when creating `INSERTS` select these ids from that table.
However I'm noob here and don't really get how I should do that and all the examples I find seem complicated.
Could someone give a helping hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing all the inserts in one statement?

```
INSERT INTO D (x, y, z)
    SELECT v.x, v.y, c.z
    FROM C CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (20, 2.9), (11, 33), (12, 2.11)
         ) v(x, y)
    WHERE Ids in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

You could also define the ids in a CTE, and then do all the `inserts` in one statement:

```
with ids(id) as (
      values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
     )
insert into d (x, y, z)
    select 20, 2.9, c.z
    from c
    where c.id in (select id from ids)
    union all
    select 11, 33, c.z
    from c
    where c.id in (select id from ids)
    union all
    . . . ;
```